# replace names in fasta

Tags: bash, awk, replace, fasta

I want to change the sequence names in a fasta file according a text file containing new names. I found several approaches but `seqkit` made a good impression, anyway I can´t get it running. `Replace key with value by key-value file`

The fasta file `seq.fa` looks like

```
>BC1
ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC
ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC
>BC2
TGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCG
GCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCG
>BC3
GCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCCCCCCC
TGCATGCATGCATG
```

and the `ref.txt` `tab delimited` text file like

```
BC1 1234
BC2 1235
BC3 1236
```

using `siqkit` in `Git Bash` runs trough the file but doesn´t change the names.

```
seqkit replace -p' (.+)$' -r' {kv}' -k ref.txt seq.fa --keep-key
```

I´m used to `r` and new to `bash` and can´t find the bug but guess I need to adjust for `tab` and `_` ? 
As in the example https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/usage/#replace part 7. `Replace key with value by key-value file` the  sequence name is tab delimited and only the second part is replaced.

Advise how to adjust the code?

Desired outcome should look like: Replacing `BC1` by the number in the text file `1234`

```
>1234
ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC
ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC
>1235
TGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCG
GCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCG
>1236
GCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCCCCCCC
TGCATGCATGCATG
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
($2 in a) && /^>/{
  print ">"a[$2]
  next
}
1
' ref.txt FS="[> ]"  seq.fa
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                          ##Starting awk program here.
FNR==NR{                       ##FNR==NR is condition which will be TRUE when 1st Input_file named ref.txt will be read.
  a[$1]=$2                     ##Creating an array named a whose index is $1 and value is $2 of current line.
  next                         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                              ##Closing BLOCK for FNR==NR condition here.
($2 in a) && /^>/{             ##Checking condition if $2 of current line is present in array a and starts with > then do following.
  print ">"a[$2]               ##Printing > and value of array a whose index is $2.
  next                         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1                              ##Mentioning 1 will print the lines(those which are NOT starting with > in Input_file seq.fa)
' ref.txt FS="[> ]"  seq.fa    ##Mentioning Input_file names here and setting FS= either space or > for Input_file seq.fa here.
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comment need to add `>1234_1` occurrence number too in output so adding following code now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$2
  b[$1]=++c[$2]
  next
}
($2 in a) && /^>/{
  print ">"a[$2]"_"b[$2]
  next
}
1
' ref.txt FS="[> ]"  seq.fa
```

Comment: nice! `awk` is right on top of my to learn list and thank you for the Explanation. Could we also add ascending numbering for duplicated names e.g. `1234` appears twice and would be named `>1234_1` and `>1234_2` or only the duplicates get ascending numbering if easier.

Comment: @KonradWeber, sure, please check my EDIT command and let me know if this looks good now?

Comment: looks just right, just found some random names that where not changed, hope I can figure that out, might be due to the `ref.txt` file different to the names in `seq.fa` .

Comment: solved! The file was not consistent, my fold. (It was `BC01` in `seq.fa` and `BC1` in the `ref.txt`. ) Thanks for your help, highly appreciated!

Comment: I was a bit to fast calling solved. Because the EDIT "just" adds to all `names` a `_1` resulting in `name_1` even thought the name is doubled in the file. I found a solution for this, not in the same code but run in a extra line here [link](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/979/how-to-append-numbers-only-on-duplicates-sequence-names). `awk -iinplace '(/^>/ && s[$0]++){$0=$0"_"s[$0]}1;' seq.fa` will add a `_2` after the name of the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

awk solution that doesn't require GNU awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}
     NF==2{$2=a[$2]; print ">" $2;next}
     1' FS='\t' ref.txt FS='>' seq.fa
```

The first statement is filling the array `a` with the content of the tab delimited file `ref.txt`.

The second statement prints all lines of the second files `seq.fa` with 2 fields given the `>` as field delimiter.

The last statement prints all lines of that same file.